# Unable to install Capistrano gem locally during Rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install Capistrano gem locally but I am getting following error while updating a Rails project from Rails 4 to Rails 5.

Here is the information:

Ruby version:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.2.3'

...

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capistrano',  '~> 3.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1', :require => false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', :require => false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', :require => false
  gem 'capistrano-thin', :require => false, :github => 'freego/capistrano-thin'
  gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'
end
```

When I try to `bundle install` all the gems, I find following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from ./bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:263:in `bin_path'
/Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.14.3) required by your /Users/albert/localDocuments/CodingArea/Clients/hanspeter/book/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the lastest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.14.3`
```

If I try to update my bundler gem, as it is suggested, I find following error:

```
bundle update --bundler                                                               [2.5.0]
Your Gemfile lists the gem annotate (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Fetching https://github.com/freego/capistrano-thin.git
Fetching https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "capistrano":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    capistrano (= 3.4.0)

  In Gemfile:
    capistrano-bundler was resolved to 1.1.4, which depends on
      capistrano (~> 3.1)

    capistrano-rvm was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
      capistrano (~> 3.0)

    capistrano-sidekiq was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      capistrano (>= 3.9.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

In my Gemfile.lock, I have following relevant information:

```
    cancancan (1.13.1)
    capistrano (3.4.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.6)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
```

It says at the end of the file:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   1.14.3
```

On the other hand, if I list my local gems, I have following version of bundler:

```
gem list
```

Bundler version:

```
bundler (2.0.1)
```

I guess because `bundle install` is not working yet, the Gemfile.lock is not being updated.

In my local gems, I can not see the `capistrano` gem.

When I try to install the `capistrano` gem, following happens:

```
gem install capistrano --verbose                                                      [2.5.0]
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.gems.rubyforge.org
HEAD http://gems.rubyforge.org/api/v1/dependencies
301 Moved Permanently
HEAD https://rubygems.org
200 OK
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.gems.github.com
HEAD http://gems.github.com/api/v1/dependencies
301 Moved Permanently
HEAD http://gems.github.io/api/v1/dependencies
404 Not Found
GET http://gems.github.com/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
301 Moved Permanently
GET http://gems.github.io/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
404 Not Found
GET http://gems.github.com/specs.4.8.gz
301 Moved Permanently
GET http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz
404 Not Found
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org?gems=capistrano
200 OK
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
```

Apparently it is found, in the `https://rubygems.org?gems=capistrano` url. But then comes this marshal file error. I don't know how to debug this.

In the debug mode, I get following information:

```
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/resolv.rb:170 - LoadError
Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/resolv.rb:546 - _rubygems._tcp.gems.rubyforge.org
Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/resolv.rb:546 - _rubygems._tcp.gems.rubyforge.org.local
Exception `Resolv::ResolvError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/resolv.rb:491 - DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.gems.rubyforge.org
Exception `Resolv::ResolvError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/resolv.rb:491 - DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.gems.github.com
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:274 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/api/v1/dependencies)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:304 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/api/v1/dependencies)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/albert/.gem/specs/gems.github.com%80
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:274 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:304 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/albert/.gem/specs/gems.github.com%80
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:274 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:304 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:269 - bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz)
Exception `TypeError' at /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb:118 - incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb:118:in `load'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb:118:in `versions'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb:55:in `find_all'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb:55:in `block in find_all'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb:54:in `map'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb:54:in `find_all'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:31:in `find_all'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:155:in `find_all'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:56:in `add_always_install'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:478:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:194:in `install_gem'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:255:in `block in install_gems'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `each'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `install_gems'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `execute'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command.rb:313:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:171:in `process_args'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:141:in `run'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run'
    /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

My gem sources are:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://gems.rubyforge.org/
http://gems.github.com
https://rubygems.org/
```

Could someone help me to find the issue and installing Capistrano?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle`?

Comment: you were right, thanks a lot. I thought with bundle install file is overwritten, i.e., deleted and then written again.